# Changing whole table background on hovering a tr

Tags: html, html-table

I have a table with a background image and two `<td>`.
I'd basically would like to change the whole table background image on hovering one of the td. Is there any way I could do that?

Comment: Yes it is possible, but you will have to do it via JS — simply because there is no parent/ancestor selector in CSS. p/s: Welcome to StackOverflow, and you might want to find out how to create a [minimal, concrete and verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so as to provide us with more details of your problem. For your case, a reduced markup in a code snippet would be a great place to start.

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery:

```
$( function() {
  $('#OneOfTheTD').click( function() {
    $(this).parent("table").toggleClass("class-with-other-background");
  } );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<table id="ch">
            <tr>
                <td>hsadkj</td>
                <td>asdy</td>
                <td>jghsdk</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td onmouseover="chan()">dsjh</td>
                <td>ksahd</td>
                <td>kldfjh</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

JS:

```
function chan()
{
    document.getElementById("ch").style.backgroundImage="url";
}
```